# Angular 5+ http post issue

Tags: angular, rest, json-server

I'm able to retrieve my objects just fine from a JSON file that resides on my localhost.  However, upon post, I get.

```
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

On the mock object I'm passing in, If I add an id property and some random number, it works.  But I don't want to have to pass in an id.

Here's the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class TileService {

  tiles$ = new Subject<any>();
  details$  = new Subject<any>();
  messages$  = new Subject<any>();

  private tilesUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/tiles';

  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTiles(): Observable<Tile[]> {
    return this.http.get<Tile[]>(this.tilesUrl);
  }

   createTile(t: Tile) {
    return this.http.post<Tile>(this.tilesUrl, t, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.error);
        console.log(err.name);
        console.log(err.message);
        console.log(err.status);
      }
    );
   }

}
```

Here is where I pass in the mock object:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-available-tiles',
  templateUrl: './available-tiles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./available-tiles.component.css']
})

export class AvailableTilesComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Available Tiles';

  tiles: Tile[];


  mockNewTile = {
    title: 'GO',
    description: 'Go is an open source programming language that makes it easy to build simple, reliable, and efficient software.',
    code: {
        snippetA: 'something here.',
        }
  };

  constructor(private tileService: TileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tileService.getTiles().subscribe(x => this.tiles = x);
  }

  addTile(t: Tile) {
    this.tileService.tileStream(t);
    this.tileService.messageStream( t.title +  ' tile added.');
  }

  createTile() {
    this.tileService.createTile(this.mockNewTile);
  }
}
```

I'm using json-server to allow REST operations on my localhost.

Contents of http://localhost:3000/tiles.json

```
{
  "tiles": [
    {
      "title": Language A",
      "description": "Language A description.",
      "code": {
        "snippetA": "lang snippet a1",
        "snippetB": "lang snippet a2",
        "snippetC": "lang snippet a3"
      }
    },
       {
      "title": Language B",
      "description": "Language B description.",
      "code": {
        "snippetA": "lang snippet b1",
        "snippetB": "lang snippet b2",
        "snippetC": "lang snippet b3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I suspect that error is triggered somewhere else, since you are not accessing the id property, at least in your code here.

Comment: Nowhere in my code do I have an ID which is passed nor does my Tile model require it.

Comment: @Jeremiah2911 You just pinpointed the error then... you should provide what the server needs

Comment: How do I do that without requiring the user to enter an id? Random nun gen I suppose. And why does the server need an id anyway? Unless  that’s best way to have a property unique to the tile.

Comment: That would require knowing what server you're talking to, and its API

Comment: Can show us the back end code ? It is where the error is generated.

Comment: I used json-server to set up the “back end” I can show you the JSON  file on the server which is my local host. I’ll update the question.

Comment: your code is correct. I think this problem from api . Is this API tested by [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can solve this issue.

1. If you have access to the back-end code you can change it to ignore the id field form the request accepted. Instead to auto increment the id field.
2. You can pass an id without the user entering an id.

---

```
npm install uuid --save
```

---

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

 mockNewTile = {
      id : uuid(),
      title: 'GO',
      description: 'Go is an open source programming language that makes it easy to build simple, reliable, and efficient software.',
      code: {
          snippetA: 'something here.',
       }
   };
```

---

I hope that helps. If it does not work plz feel free to comment. I am right there.

Comment: Thank you. I like your 1) solution but not sure how to do that since the backend setup was automated by Node's json-server.  Your 2) solution did the trick.